# CSS content with verticaly title on side

Tags: css, css-float

I have CSS boxes of variable height set to float left inside a bigger div.
Now I would like to add a title where the text appears vertically (rotated 90 degrees) on the left side of the box, like shown on the link below(sorry can't post images yet).

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/259/cssquestion.png

I have tried everything but so far with no luck. I assume I need to make two div ('title' and 'content') inside a 'wrapper' div but whatever position settings I use on the title div appears totally wrong.

Is this possible at all in CSS or will I have to use some JS to produce align the heights of 'title' and 'content' dynamically?

Thanks,
Nicolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/3r2Sk/1/

The primary code you need is

```
-webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(270deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
-moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(270deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
-ms-transform: scale(1) rotate(270deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
-o-transform: scale(1) rotate(270deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
transform: scale(1) rotate(270deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
```

Ran into various issues with positioning, rotating elements can be finicky.  Most of the position and widths and heights will have to be adapted to your particular situation.  It would be best to start from the ground up and just copy the transform code.  Use the above link as a reference.

Comment: very helpful article for understanding this kind of thing: [link](http://css-tricks.com/sideways-headers/)

Comment: I was along the correct path then, combining the above and what you see in this article will solve your problem Nicolas.

Comment: Thank you both, very interesting article. Didn't know about modernizr which seems like a pretty useful library!

Answer (score 0):

put `transform:rotate(180deg);` on your `title` div, float it to the left and it should do the work.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is a common one related to vertically positioning elements, only the problem is a bit more complicated because you're using `transform: rotate` at 270degrees. When you rotate an element, the browser draws it at first as if it was not rotated, and then displays the rotated version, so you end up with overlapping properties sometimes if you aren't careful.

One solution is to split up the drawing of the content and background of the element.

I usually handle vertical alignment in this way: set an outer element to `display: table` and an inner element to `display: table-cell`, in this way you can set `vertical-align: middle` to the text in the inner element.

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/MsBKQ/9/

Seems to be displayed on all browsers properly: http://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20table